# lottie-vue.js is not loading animation correctly in first cycle

Tags: nuxt.js, lottie

I am developing a scene animation using lottie-vue.js. It is working well in demo generated version but it is not working properly in Nuxt.js. It needs a one cycle to get working well. Any idea to solve this problem?

[Online working version](http://www.greatsoft.uz)